# Looking for lightweight php based cms with rest-api

Tags: php, cms, api, mobile, rest

I am looking for a PHP based lightweight CMS (not [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/)) for my web based blog and also I need to access the services via (Restful) API for my native mobile app as well.

Can you help me to find one? I'm pretty sure there are plenty of CMS available with backend API. I don't like Wordpress because it's too heavy with many functionalities. My main idea is not to re-invent something which is already there.

Comment: So what features/functionalities do you need? Should it be free or commercial? Any budget? Please [edit] your question and make it a bit more detailed and specific. For a guide, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) The better you describe your needs, the better answers can fit them :)

Comment: Yes there are sooo many. That's why we can't help you if you don't give us more information about your needs.

Answer (score 4):

If Wordpress doesn't fit your needs, then you might want to look at a typical alternative that might fit all the requirements you specified so far: [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/).

Here are some more reasons why I think it might be a good fit:

- PHP based.
- CMS.
- not Wordpress.
- can be used for a web based blog.
- can be accessed the services via (Restful) API (for a native mobile app).
- backend API available.
- to reduce the amount of functionalities, you can simply disabled quite a few of the features that come "out of the box" (with Drupal core, if you don't add any contributed modules).
- you won't re-invent something which is already there.

One can "argue" if Drupal is yes or no "lightweight" though ...

Did I mention it's free, and open source? There is even an [SE-site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to it ...